# Elastic search memoryerror on bulk insert

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch, encode

Im inserting 5000 records at once into elastic search 
Total Size of these records is: 33936 (I got this using sys.getsizeof())

Elastic Search version: 1.5.0
Python 2.7
Ubuntu

Here is the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_indexing.py", line 67, in <module>
    index_policy_content(datatable, source, policyids)
  File "run_indexing.py", line 60, in index_policy_content
    bulk(elasticsearch_instance, actions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/helpers.py", line 148, in bulk
    for ok, item in streaming_bulk(client, actions, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/helpers.py", line 107, in streaming_bulk
    resp = client.bulk(bulk_actions, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 70, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 568, in bulk
    params=params, body=self._bulk_body(body))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 259, in perform_request
    body = body.encode('utf-8')
MemoryError
```

Please help me resolve the issue.

Thanks & Regards,
Afroze

Comment: is this an ES issue or are you spending your available memory encoding to UTF-8? How much RAM does your machine have? Are you using ES_HEAP_SIZE?

Comment: Start with 10 records, then 50, then 100, etc... until it fails. But judging by the Traceback, it doesn't seem to be an ES issue, more in Python, I guess. Can you also paste the relevant logs from your ES server while you're doing the bulk indexing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd say this memory error is happening within python as it loads and serializes its data. Try cutting way back on the batch sizes until you get something that works, and then binary search upward until it fails again. That should help you figure out a safe batch size to use.

(Other useful information you might want to include: amount of memory in the server you're running your python process on, amount of memory for your elasticsearch server node(s), amount of heap allocated to Java.)

Comment: Thank you. It was something with python. I tried to manage the memory usage in the python code that i wrote and it worked.